# Cannot add css background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

[image][[image: 1]]

Using bootstrap, I'm working on creating main page.
However, for some reason, I can't add background image.
I tried adding on css body, adding on html ...etc
It just doesn't change anything on my website.

```
body {
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif; 
  background-image: url("/images/slider_3.jpg")!important;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff; }

::selection {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff; }
.btn
{

  width: 21%;
 height:250px;
  border: none;
  background-color:  #70B1D1;

  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center; 

}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #f7f5ed;
}
a {
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
  -o-transition: .3s all ease;
  transition: .3s all ease; }
  a:hover {
    text-decoration: none; }

.text-black {
  color: #000 !important; }

.text-white {
  color: #fff !important; }

/* Navbar */
/* Blocks */
.site-section {
  padding: 7rem 0; }
```

This is part of my CSS.

Comment: Your actual code will be more helpful than this.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the image is correct? probably needs to be `../images/slider_3.jpg` but depends on where the html page is in relation to the images directory.

Comment: @RobMoll I've tried ("images/sliders_3.jpg") but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your background image overwrited. You can use `important` options to make it work

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. How does important option works?

Answer (score 0):

Your must specify the path like this:

```
background-image: url("../../images/slider_3.jpg");
```

or if your `images` folder is in root you can try:

```
background-image: url("/images/slider_3.jpg");
```

Comment: try this: `background-image: url("/images/slider_3.jpg") !important;` or `background-image: url("../../images/slider_3.jpg") !important;` then try the hard refresh on your browser by pressing `ctrl + f5`